Microsoft Graph api for alertRules and alertRecords not working with CloudPC.ReadAll permissions
We are trying to get alert rules and records using Microsoft Graph apis (beta version). Please find below the details:
APIs:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/monitoring/alertRules
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/monitoring/alertRecords
Permissions given: CloudPC.Read.All (Delegated and Application)
Alerts status is ON in Azure portal. But we are getting 403 forbidden error while accessing these apis. Please let me know if any more permissions or settings to be done.
Thanks in advance.
# Define the required variables
$clientId = ''
$clientSecret = ''
$tenantId = ''
$authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($tenantId)"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$apiVersion = "beta"
$objs= @()

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 
[Net.SecurityProtocolTYpe]::Tls12

# Authenticate and acquire access token
$tokenEndpoint = "$authority/oauth2/token"
$body = @{
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    resource      = $resource
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Method 
POST -Body $body

# Get access token from the response
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

# Define the API endpoint

$apiEndpoint="https://graph.microsoft.com/$($apiVersion)/deviceManagement/monitoring/alertRules"
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $($accessToken)" }

$apiResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiEndpoint -Method Get - 
   Headers $headers

$outputs = $apiResponse.Value | Select 
displayName,severity,description,alertRuleTemplate
foreach($output in $outputs)
{
    $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{                    
                                                
    displayName=$output.displayName                                                    
                                                
    severity=$output.severity
                                                
    description=$output.description
                                                
    alertRuleTemplate = $output.alertRuleTemplate                                                    
                                                })

    $objs += $obj
}

$objs

Error Message:
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) 
Forbidden.


The issue is the controller in the server.  it is probably a an authorize/role issue.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Could you share your script? To check how do you connect to the Graph API.

Hi, thanks for the reply. Added script and the error message in the body, please check.
